# Jetty Proxy servlet not sending all the modified content

Tags: json, servlets, jetty

I am using Jetty's proxy servlet to route requests from a front-end client to Couch database. In addition to proxying, I am injecting an additional details, to the incoming request that is used by the CouchDB. HTTP request is modified by extending [`HTTPServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html). When I override the `getContentLength` method and recalculate the size of the `inputStream`, only the content of size of the original request is sent to CouchDB and since the input JSON is invalid Couch DB issues a Bad Request(400 HTTP) code. In the Jetty logger, I see that `contentWritten != contentLength` message. Once I remove Content-Length header altogether, Jetty sends the request as expected copying all the content to the proxied request. Even if this approach works, I am wondering what really causes Jetty to not send the modified request content even when the correct content length is set by overriding the `getContentLength` method of `ServletInputStream`.

I am using Jetty 8.1.3 version and all requests are JSON requests/responses. I have also subclassed the `ServletInputStream` class and `read()` method, so I don't think there is any problem with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a chunked encoding bug fixed recently in Jetty 7.6.10-SNAPSHOT and 8.1.10-SNAPSHOT.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401382

Fixed in Jetty-7 (and then merged into Jetty-8)

- [Commit #1](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?h=jetty-7&id=27cad4960b06f2f5277bd35ef3dc677caedec844)
- [Commit #2](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/commit/?h=jetty-7&id=bed3ea04f8fd9731a73b0d97c10b9f35fdb950b2)

You can use Jetty 7.6.10-SNAPSHOT or 8.1.10-SNAPSHOT from the [oss.sonatype.org SNAPSHOTS repository](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/jetty-snapshots/).

The 7.6.10 and 8.1.10 releases are likely going to occur in the first week of March 2013.

Yes, Jetty-7 and Jetty-8 are the same codebase, developed in parallel, and even released in parallel, with the only difference being the servlet spec supported by each.  (Jetty-7 is Servlet 2.5, Jetty-8 is Servlet 3.0)

Comment: Request received by Couch DB has only the first part of the request and other content is lost. As I understood in the [bug]https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401382 Jetty should send only the last chunk of the request. In my case its only the first few segments being sent. Is that right?

Comment: Its a bit more complex than that.  When the downstream response is HTTP chunked (only happens with http chunked responses), and then received on the ProxyServlet in an async fashion, the ProxyServlet attempts to preserve the chunking but fails to do so in 100% of cases.  In some situations the async chunks can overwrite each other.  This is what the bug reported, and the fix in code fixed.